# How to close sub tab from lightning component button click

Tags: lightning, console, lightning-out

I have a vf page in which I have embedded a lightning component ( lightning out ). I'm having a lightning button called "Save". On clicking this, I need to close the sub tab ( currently I'm displaying this component in console application).

I don't have a clue to how to proceed this as I'm completely stuck.

Please help me out with this.

Comment: Its Classic Console or lightning console?

Comment: Classic Console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to close a tab in the classic console, you have to use [Salesforce Console Integration Toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console.htm). The toolkit contains [closeTab()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_closetab.htm#sforce_api_console_closetab) that allows you to close the tab.

The challenge here is you can only use Salesforce Console Integration Toolkit from VF page and not lightning component. So you have to find a way for your VF page to close tab.

To communicate between lightning component inside a VF page we use [Window.postMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/lightning-visualforce-communication.html).

So when save is completed, you have to post a message from lightning component to VF page. The VF page will have a listener to it, and you will then call `closeTab()` method for SF toolkit to close the current tab.

I havent personally tried it, but in theory it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much Pranay for your idea for me to proceed atleast. Do I need to have my visualforce page to be embedded in iframe in order to communicate from lightning to vf ?

Answer (score 1):

After trying a lot of code i found, this worked for me:

1. Put that in your lightning component

   ```
   <ltng:require scripts="/support/console/34.0/integration.js"/>
   <lightning:button label="Close" onclick="{!c.closeTab}"/>
   ```
2. Call this function

   ```
   closeTab : function(component, event, helper){
      sforce.console.getEnclosingTabId(
        $A.getCallback(function(result) {
           sforce.console.closeTab(result.id);
         })
      );
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For API Version 35.0 or Later–Visualforce change it to 52.0. It worked for me.

`<ltng:require scripts="/support/console/52.0/integration.js"/>`

[Check this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_closetab.htm#sforce_api_console_closetab)